# nodejs async: multiple dependant HTTP API calls

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I'm working on a project that involves making multiple HTTP GET requests to different APIs, each requiring information from the last. I'm trying to avoid nested-callaback-and-counter-hell, and have been trying to get it working with the `async` module.

This is what I need to do: I have an array of 1..n course identifiers (`['2014/summer/iat/100/d100', '2014/spring/bisc/372/d100']`). For each course in the array, I need to fetch its course outline via a HTTP GET.

The resulting outline looks something like this:

```
{
  "info": {
    "nodePath": "2014/spring/bisc/372/d100",
    "number": "372",
    "section": "D100",
    "title": "Special Topics in Biology",
    "term": "Spring 2014",
    "description": "Selected topics in areas not currently offered...",
    "name": "BISC 372 D100",
    "dept": "BISC",
 },
 "instructor": [
    {
      "lastName": "Smith",
      "commonName": "Frank",
      "phone": "1 555 555-1234",
      "email": "franksmith@school.edu",
      "name": "Frank Smith",
      "roleCode": "PI"
    },
    {
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "commonName": "John",
      "phone": "1 555 555-9876",
      "email": "johndoe@school.edu",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "roleCode": "PI"
    }
  ]
}
```

(a bunch of non-relevant fields omitted)

Each outline object may contain an `instructor` property which is an array of 0..n instructor objects for the course. For each member of the `instructor` array, I need to then call another API to get additional data. When that call returns, I need to insert it into the right instructor object.

Finally, when everything is done, the data gets passed to a template for express to render and return to the client.

I've tried getting this working using `async` and had some success with `async.waterfall` when doing a proof-of-concept with only getting one of the instructor profiles (e.g. not looping over the array, just getting instructor[0]). The async module's docs are comprehensive, but pretty dense and I'm having a hard time determining what I actually need to do. I had a Frankenstein combination of various nested async calls which still didn't work.

I don't really care how I accomplish the task - flow-control, promises, magic pixie dust, whatever. Any hints greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Q for promises, you can probably do something like this:

```
return Q
.all(course_ids.map(function(course) {
    return HTTP.GET(course); // Assuming this returns a promise
}))
.then(function(course_data) {
    var instructors = [];

    course_data.forEach(function(course) {
        var p = Q
            .all(course.instructor.map(function(instructor) {
                return HTTP.GET(instructor.id);
            }))
            .then(function(instructors) {
                course.instructors_data = instructors;

                return course;
            });

        promises.push(p);
    });

    return Q.all(promises);
});
```

Will resolve with an array containing the courses, each of which contains
an array of instructor data in its `instructors_data` value.

Comment: I've decided to try promises for this. I've got the first step, fetching the outlines for the courses, working; that was stupid-easy. I'm having trouble figuring out how to promisify the next part, grabbing the profiles for each instructor for a course and stuffing them into the right place. I've got it working the longhand way, using callbacks and counters. https://gist.github.com/grahamb/11306874

Answer (score 1):

You could use `async.each()`, which would do the API requests in parallel (assuming there is no concurrent API request limits on the server side, if that is the case, use `async.eachLimit()` instead):

```
async.each(instructors, function(instructor, callback) {

  // call API here, store result on `instructor`,
  // and call `callback` when done

}, function(err){
  if (err)
    console.log('An error occurred while processing instructors');
  else
    console.log('All instructors have been processed successfully');
});
```